# "File Sharing" Option under "Sharing" not Visible after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: settings, sharing, 23.04

After upgrading to 23.04, the option "File Sharing", normally listed first of four options under "Sharing" in Settings, is simply not appearing, as per image below:

[image]

I can still access shared folders from a remote Ubuntu machine, but only after enabling the other sharing options (Media Sharing probably enabled that access).

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 23.04, there's an application used for personal file sharing called `gnome-user-share.` [Ubuntu documentation is located here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-personal.html), while [Gnome personal file sharing details (more extensive) are located here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-user-share/stable/index.html.en).

After installing `gnome-user-share` you'll see the addition of the File Sharing option in the Setting/Sharing menu.